# int *p=somearray but (p+1) is not equal to address of somearray[1]. Why?

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[]={11,12,13},*p;
    printf("%x\n",a);

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
       printf("%x  ",(a+i));

    p=(&a)+1;    //LINE1
    printf("this is this %x\n",p); //LINE2
    printf("%d  ",*p);
    printf("%d\n",*(p-1));
    return 0;
}
```

After the pointer arithmetic on LINE1 why is the address printed by LINE2 is not equivalent to a[1]? Instead there is a additional difference of 4 bytes.

Comment: Could you please share the output of the program. It is hard otherwise to understand, at least for me

Comment: `printf` `%x` takes an `unsigned int`, not an `int *`.

Comment: `a` is of type `int(*)[3]`. The expression `(&a)+1` offsets the pointer `sizeof(int(*)[3])`. Take out the `&`.

Comment: `p = &a + 1` is a type error. `&a` has type `int (*)[3]`, not `int *`. Your compiler should have complained about this.

Comment: This is where I executed it: https://www.onlinegdb.com/ryO87VBo-

Comment: @JeffMercado your comment cleared it for me,thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write

```
&a
```

you are getting the address of the array `a`. Since the type of the array `a` is `int [3]`, the type of this pointer is `int (*) [3]`, a pointer to an array of three integers.

When you then write

```
&a + 1
```

you are saying "go to the object one past the one pointed at `a`." Remember that `a` has type `int (*) [3]`, so C interprets this to point "point at the array of three `int`s that comes after the array of three `int`s pointed at by `a`." As a result, you'll be pointing 3 × `sizeof(int)` bytes past the base of the array, which isn't where you'll find the element `a[1]`.

You probably should have gotten a compiler warning from the line

```
p = (&a) + 1
```

because the types are wrong. The pointer `p` is an `int *` and the expression on the right-hand side has type `int (*) [3]`. Compiling with a high warning setting might have alerted you to the fact that *something* was wrong, which might have tipped you off that something wasn't quite right here. I'd recommend compiling with high warning settings going forward, since many warnings flagged by compilers these days are legitimate issues.

There are a couple things you can do to fix this. One would be to write

```
&a[0] + 1
```

The expression `&a[0]` means "a pointer to the first element of `a`" and has type `int *`, so when you add one to it, C interprets this to mean "point to the next `int` after `a[0]`, which is where `a[1]` lives.

Due to array-to-pointer decay, you can also write

```
a + 1
```

because C interprets the expression `a` as a pointer to the first element of `a` (that is, `&a[0]`).

To summarize:

- Pointer arithmetic depends on the size of the underlying type.
- Writing `&a` gives you a pointer to an array of elements, not a pointer to the first element of the array. The addresses are the same, but the types are different.

Answer (score 1):

For pointer arithmetic, you should know the type of pointer.
Now here a is a pointer to an integer array of 3 elements.
i.e. data type of a is int (*) [3].

Whenever you are adding 1 to a, it will point to next memory location after 3 integers.
And type of pointer &(a[0]) is int *.

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use pointer arithmetic on elements of the array:
a is already int * so you have two options:

```
    p=(&a[0])+1;    //LINE1
```

or

```
    p=a+1;    //LINE1
```

Comment: Correct. Or just  `p=a+1;`

Comment: adding it, thks